# How to return to Anchor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, anchor

I have simply for loop with function. If i click on button (`.custom-read-more`) loop adds class called active and if i click the button again the class is removed. Simply `toggle` function.

My little issue is that if i click the button. Content is shown and if i click again content is hidden. When i hide the content user's view is at the footer of the page. I'd like return user back. For example back to anchor.

```
  let more = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-read-more');
  for (let i = 0; i < more.length; i++) {
    more[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
      more[i].parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
      more[i].classList.toggle('active');
    });
  }
```

Is it possible tell JS every even click return back to anchor or use if statement something like `if ($('.custom-read-more').hasClass('active')){"return to anchor"}`

Maybe dumb question but my programing journey just begun. :)

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)?

Comment: Take a look at the [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) method, this should help you accomplish this.